# Are there any modern X11/Xorg Browsers that compile for OSX?

Tags: software-recommendation, macports, web-browser, x11

Currently I'm using macports. I'm wondering if there are any graphical X11 browsers like Chromium, or Firefox, or the like that compile under X11 (and not native OSX). I want a browser that I can manage with an X11 Desktop Environment (like i3).

My criteria would be modern (executes javascript), graphical, and maintained. I know there are other build systems out there like Fink, and even more projects that aren't available under Fink or Macports so I'm willing to cast a wide net to find something.

Chromium would be great.

I see some threads where [people have asked similar questions](https://sourceforge.net/p/fink/mailman/message/34047822/) but most of these are at least 4 years old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@ken suggested epiphany in [this comment](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/42087#comment:9)

> Check out `epiphany`. But `webkit2-gtk` still has bugs on Mac FYI.

You can see that on [macports](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=epiphany)

I tried this browser and I was unsuccessful in getting it to install. I do not at this time believe any modern browser is compiled against X11 that runs on OSX.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your reason for wanting a browser under X11, but your needs might be met by running Chromium or Firefox in a Docker container over VNC. Then, you can use any window manager you want.

For example, here's my container that exposes Firefox through OpenBox.

[Firefox over VNC on Docker Hub](https://cloud.docker.com/u/wilfredsmith/repository/docker/wilfredsmith/alpine-firefox-vnc)

Comment: The reason /was/ because I wanted a tiling window manager.